# Delete from table A where no children exist in table A and no children exist in table B

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I have a traditional parent/child table for simple tree categorisation and a 'page' table for pages linked to the categories:

```
    **Table: cat**
    c_id
    c_name
    parent_id

    **Table: page**
    p_id
    page_name
    c_id
```

I would like to perform a deletion **only if there are no child categories in the cat table and no child pages in the page table**. I know how to do this by counting and checking first. But, want to know if it can be achieved elegantly in a single query and get the affected rows.

I've tried this and it doesn't work as *I think* it is disallowed to select from the target table in the delete query?

```
    DELETE 
    FROM cat
    WHERE c_id=x
    AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT count( DISTINCT p_id ) as pages                       
    FROM page
    WHERE c_id =x
    )
    AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT count( DISTINCT c_id ) as children                       
    FROM cat
    WHERE parent_id =x
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A DELETE JOIN will work, even when deleting from a joined table. Here we LEFT JOIN to check if there are any connections (c2 is a possible parent, and p is a possible referring page)

Finally we just DELETE the rows where there are no connections (ie the connections return as NULL);

```
DELETE c1
FROM cat c1
LEFT JOIN cat c2 
  ON c1.c_id = c2.parent_id
LEFT JOIN page p
  ON c1.c_id = p.c_id
WHERE c2.parent_id IS NULL
 AND p.c_id IS NULL
 AND c1.c_id = 1
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9980b/1).

Comment: Awesome. That is much more elegant than a few selects and conditional statements before running the delete! Thank you.